# Tomcat Server Start Issue

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

I am trying to start tomcat server,But i have face some problem .

Problem is:

when ever i click tomcat7.exe,it is opening and immeditely closing means not started the server.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]

Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\****>cd..
C:\Users>cd..
C:\>cd C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.68\bin
C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.68\bin>tomcat7.exe start
C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.68\bin>
```

I did't get the problem.

So please suggest me how to start tomcat server?

Comment: "I didn't get the problem." - That's good! What's your question, then?

Comment: i need to start the tomcat server.@cricket_007

Comment: i explained the problem above.if you give suggestion then give otherwise leave it.@cricket_007

Comment: Please try running from the command prompt instead of clicking on the icon. If you get errors from that, include them in your question. Please see http://crunchify.com/how-to-start-stop-apache-tomcat-server-via-command-line-setup-as-windows-service/

Comment: see above one now.@cricket_007

Comment: check if any other service is  running on your system that occupies port number you mentioned for tomcat..that may be the cause

Comment: So no log files are generated? I've never used Tomcat. What exactly is opening and closing?

Comment: try command netstat -a in command prompt. It will list all ports which are used by system. Check for :8080. If its there, means something is already using it.

Comment: Please take a minute to see what is [the topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). After you have done that, take a look at `C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.68\logs` in general and at a file called `catalina.out` in particular.